# How to assign pixels to each part of the image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a functional that will apply a kaleidoscope effect to an image.

and then basically "pasting" the four images from each quadrants onto the new image using four separate nested for loops, but the question is how do I divide new_img into four quadrants, then pasting the four images to each quadrant?

Comment: `I cannot import anything else other than importing` => can you import `os` and `sys`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare each image for "kaleidoscope" separately and then paste it onto resulted image:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.png')
w, h = image.size
w_new = int(w/2)
h_new = int(h/2)
image.thumbnail((w_new, h_new), Image.ANTIALIAS)

images = [((0, 0), image.copy().rotate(180).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)),
          ((w_new, 0), image.copy().rotate(180)),
          ((0, h_new), image.copy()),
          ((w_new, h_new), image.copy().transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT))]

result = Image.new('RGB', (w, h))
[result.paste(img[1], img[0]) for img in images]
result.save('result.png')
```

Output is:

[image]